# Can't get access to videos on Firefox

Tags: xubuntu, video, browser

I use Firefox on Ubuntu but I can't watch some videos because I don't have permission. Also I can't enter a meeting on meeting burner because of the same thing.

The videos I can't watch is videos on news site. CNN for example. When I click on the videos nothing happens. My browser say **The connection is not secure** but I know it is secure.

It also tells me **You have not granted this site any special permission**. 
So I guess I have to grant permission to this site - how can I do that?

This is some kind of security feature I would like to deactivate. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add some details about the problem - as example: error messages and similar. Is that a firefox specific issue?  Could you provide us an URL ?

Comment: Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: I already done that but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Please check if that happens with other browsers (i.e. Chrome) aswell

Comment: It's working on chrome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. **The connection is not secure** is not a problem. Firefox reporting right now that, my connection to AskUbuntu is not secure!! This is something related to the SSL certificates and actually this doesn't cause a video to not playing!!

Secondly, **You have not granted this site any special permission** is also good. Actually very good! It means you have not given the site to use your webcam, audio etc. I've posted a picture of my permissions for AskUbuntu below.

You can Check them by clicking on the little icon left of the address bar, clicking the `>` icon after website name and then **More information**.

[image: permissions]

I believe, you can't play the video because the video is not auto-playing. Just click on the black screen of the video. It should start playing. Since, you said, you installed codecs already.

Comment: Thank for the answer- I have only installed ubuntu-restricted-extras, I do not know what codecs means. When I click on the video It don't start and there is simply a white screen.

Comment: @OlePetersen which video it was. can you link it here?

Comment: These ones for example: http://edition.cnn.com/videos

Comment: @OlePetersen can you play other videos?

Comment: Only videos on youtube.

Comment: @OlePetersen I think you're missing the flashplugin. Install these pacakge `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` and try again

Comment: I installed it but I still have the same problem. Maybe I should allow the plugin, when I launch the video?

Comment: @OlePetersen of course!! If you don't allow it, how could it play! I thought you're already allowing it

Comment: How can I allow it? It doesn't ask me when I launch the video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44941/discussion-between-anwar-and-ole-petersen).